# Damage to sd card

Tags: sd-card

My memmory card is '16gb strontium micro sd HC'. I have worked it on my mobile. One day suddenly my phone doesn't detected it. Then i put it on my card reader and plugged into ubuntu 10.04 laptop. then it opens and i can view the files. then i copied the whole files into laptop and tried to format it. but i can't.

```
Error formatting volume

Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: 
    Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdb1: Input/output error
```

also i can't copy any files to it. The files on it is readable but can't edit. 
My card reader have no problems. Please help me.

Comment: Is the write-protection switch on the side of it in the wrong position?

Comment: Also, **upgrade Ubuntu**! You haven't been getting important security updates for *years*.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please update Ubuntu

2) please run **sudo gparted** in the terminal and try to format the sd card using this utility.